# Kid science picture book 1970s with Marie Curie

Tags: story-identification

Looking for title of kids picture book from the 1970s or early 1980s about science. It was like an encyclopedia or "what do I want to be when I grow up" type of book. Explained about Marie Curie (among others, book was not about her specifically).  Might also have mentioned Helen Keller, joy of learning with examples. It inspired my sister to pursue a career in microbiology so I'd like to try to get a copy. It was not a library book; my parents owned it or got it for us. They also got us a series of books about the human body and left them laying around (to explain puberty basically). That was a set of maybe 3 red books. But I suspect the one I'm looking for probably was not in that set. I can visualize the 2-3 pages that showed Marie Curie with test tubes or something and it said unfortunately Marie died from her discovery. Definitely color illustrations, not photographs. Larger print, smaller words for elementary grade level reading.  Glossy pages typical of picture books.  I tried Google but get either books wholy about Marie or books written last 10 years. I might recognize the cover if I saw it. My parents' house is hoarded so the book might be there but would take years to find if it hasn't been destroyed from mildew, insects, etc. Oh and I think the discovery of penicillin was in it. So maybe accidental discoveries themed book.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about any kind of speculative fiction. You might want to try [literature.se] instead.